# Moving checked values to another block and appending them within <li> lists

Tags: jquery

I want to move the selected list items from one block (block 1) another block (block 2). After moving to block 2, if I delete the item from block 2, it should append back to block 1.

Here is my code:

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="left">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" onclick="addval(this)" />Option 1</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" onclick="addval(this)" />Option 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="right">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The script:

```
function addval(x){
     values1 = $(x).val();
     $('#right ul').append("<li><img src='http://www.msshifi.com/skin/frontend/msshifi/default/images/delete-icon.gif' name="+ values1 +" onclick='removeval(this,values1)'></img>"+ values1 +"</li>");
     $(x).parent().remove();

 }
 function removeval(y,val){
     values2 = val;
     $('#left ul').append("<li><input type='checkbox' value="+ values2 +" name="+ values2 +" onclick='addval(this)' />"+ values2 +"</li>");
     $(y).parent().remove();

 }
```

The CSS:

```css
div { border:1px #ccc solid; height:100px; overflow:auto; width:200px; background:#f1f1f1; }
ul { margin:0; padding:0; }
ul li { list-style:none; }
```

Working demo of the same is available online at : http://jsfiddle.net/prajan55/maLqV/

Kindly help.. thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem here, everything seems to be working the way you want it to?

Comment: @Shef: There was a little coding error over appending the html + variable.. quotes around the variable was missing which is now fixed (thanks to sje397 for pointing it out). Now its working fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing a few quotes.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/maLqV/7/

Fixed code:

```
function addval(x){
     values1 = $(x).val();
     $('#right ul').append("<li><img src='http://www.msshifi.com/skin/frontend/msshifi/default/images/delete-icon.gif' name='"+ values1 +"' value='" + values1 + "' onclick='removeval(this, \"" + values1 + "\")'></img>"+ values1 +"</li>");
     $(x).parent().remove();

 }
 function removeval(y,val){
     values2 = val;
     $('#left ul').append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='"+ values2 +"' name='"+ values2 +"' onclick='addval(this)' />"+ values2 +"</li>");
     $(y).parent().remove();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Anyway, its still confusing for me to appending html along with variables. So, i simply copy-paste your above code and use it :)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a slightly different implementation:

```
var checkedList = $('#right ul');
var unCheckedList = $('#left  ul');

$('input:checkbox').click(
    function(){
        if (this.checked){
            $(this).closest('li').appendTo(checkedList);
        }
        else if (!this.checked){
            $(this).closest('li').appendTo(unCheckedList);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/maLqV/10/).

This preserves the details of the checkbox and text, whereas your implementation seemed to remove the label, or the number *from* the label (which seems to have been resolved by [@sje397's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477554/moving-checked-values-to-another-block-and-appending-them-within-li-lists/6477579#6477579)), but also this version allows for the click handler to be removed from the `onclick` attribute of the elements. Which may, or may not, be a bonus.

Comment: Your suggestion is simple yet detailed though. I have noted it down. Thanks for showing it up with a demo screen.